# Multi-Tenancy System With Separate Databases in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to create implementing database per tenant strategy. but I don't understand how I actually will do that.I followed this link  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/848111/Multi-Tenancy-System-With-Separate-Databases-in-MV     but I work with asp.net core MVC. I am an absolute beginner.how I create a separate database for different users. please help.

Comment: The solution I've linked to is much better than the answer below as the connection strings are hardcoded in the accepted answer. This will not help you with a multi-tenant solution whereby you want to be able to add a new tenant without having to do a code release: https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-database-per-tenant/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how is your model design but what you want is how to create and use multiple databases in the project.

You could follow the steps below:

- Create first database

  1. Model Design:

     ```
     public class Account
     {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         public string Name { get; set; }
     }
     ```
  2. Create DbContext:

     ```
     public class FirstContext : DbContext
     {
          public FirstContext (DbContextOptions<FirstContext> options)
              : base(options)
          {
          }

          public DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
     }
     ```
  3. Add connection string in appsettings.json:

     ```
     "ConnectionStrings": {
         "FirstContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FirstUser;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
     }
     ```
  4. Configure Startup.cs:

     ```
      public class Startup
      {
          public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
          {
              Configuration = configuration;
          }

          public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

          public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
          {
              services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
              {
                  // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                  options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                  options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
              });
              services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

               //add this...
              services.AddDbContext<FirstContext>(options =>
                  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FirstContext")));
          }

          public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
          {

              app.UseHttpsRedirection();
              app.UseStaticFiles();
              app.UseCookiePolicy();

              app.UseMvc(routes =>
              {
                  routes.MapRoute(
                      name: "default",
                      template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
              });
          }
      }
     ```

  5.Run command to create database(This way called code-first in EF Core):

  ```
  PM> add-migration init
  PM> update-database
  ```

  6.Then you could find the database in `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`->`Database` in `SQL Server Object Explorer`(in menu tab open `View`->choose `SQL Server Object Explorer`):

  [image]
- Create second database

  Repeat the 1-4 steps:

  Model:

  ```
  public class User
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  DbContext:

  ```
   public class SecondContext : DbContext
   {
       public SecondContext(DbContextOptions<FirstContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }

       public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
   }
  ```

  appsettings.json:

  ```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
   "FirstContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FirstContext-ed05c500-1e05-4d2c-876d-02172e464153;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
   "SecondContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SecondUser;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
   }
  ```

  Startup.cs:

  ```
  services.AddDbContext<FirstContext>(options =>
                       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FirstContext")));

   //add this...
  services.AddDbContext<SecondContext>(options =>
                       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecondContext")));
  ```

  What is different is that you contain more than one dbcontext,so you need specific the dbcontext name when you run command to create the database:

  ```
  PM> add-migration init2 -context secondcontext
  PM> update-database -context secondcontext
  ```
- For how to get the different user data:

  ```
  public class AccountsController : Controller
  {
       private readonly FirstContext _context;
       private readonly SecondContext _context2;
       public AccountsController(FirstContext context, SecondContext context2)
       {
           _context = context;
           _context2 = context2;
       }

       public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
       {
           var user1 = _context.Account.ToList();
           var user2 = _context2.User.ToList();
           return View();
       }
  }
  ```

Comment: I want to create one application that is the different user has different database dynamically. this separate database is will created dynamically when any user registers.

Comment: I appreciate it. 
 but I need something different.  for example: "StudentId, Student name, Phone No" assume these are models. the different student has different "StudentId, Student Name, Phone No". when students log in to their accounts after register, then they show their own Name, Id, and phone number and did not show other student details.

Comment: @David i am looking for the sam functionality,,did you find anything for it?

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz i am found a article exact what i need about multitanent.if you want this link,you can ask me.i will provide this link.

Comment: also this answer is help me alot.